# Name of door/cabinet knob that operates two bolts at once

Tags: cabinets, hardware, doorknob

I've seen knobs that when twisted operate two bolts, however I can't find them online because I don't know what they are called.

An example might be on cabinet where a knob in the center of one door has a bolt to the top and bottom. I think I've seen it usually where the bolts are surface mounted on the inside of the door.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for **Cremone Bolt**. They are a type of cabinet surface bolt latch that operates two rods or bars, usually oriented vertically with a latch bar throwing to the top and the bottom.

[image]

Thanks to Van Dyke's Restoration for the pic.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this twice; one for the answer, the other for the image credit.